# Is there a setting to show assemblies as they are loaded during debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, assemblies, visual-studio-debugging, output-window

I believe there is a setting (or combination of settings) in Visual Studio that allow you to see in the Immediate Window (or Output Window, I can't remember which), the timestamp and name of an assembly as it is loaded while debugging. I used to have this switched on as it is very useful for finding performance issue areas. Sadly however, when VS recently decided to undock all my windows for no good reason, I had to reset my VS settings and have now lost this.

I can't find for the life of me which setting it was that I had switched on.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the Output window, change the "Show output from" combo to Debug if necessary.  Right-click the window and tick "Module load messages".  And any others you might want to see.

Answer (score 19):

Apart from reading Debug output messages in Output window, you can also use **Modules Window** (at least in Visual Studio 2013) which gives you a nice searchable list of loaded modules with various additional details:

**Debug -> Windows -> Modules** 
[image: modules window screenshot]

Comment: By the way, the window (as well as the menu item that show is) is available only while debugging. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62271562/2157640