# Why my Visual Studio Community 2019 doesn't have the Modules option under Debug > Windows and how to repair it?

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, visual-studio-2019

As title says, I cannot see any "Modules" submenu under Debug > Windows, and the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+U does nothing.

[image: My menus]

Just restored Visual Studio by Installer, nothing.

I have VS 2019 Community version 16.6.1, Italian version.

Am I missing something or it is a bug? How to fix?

Comment: You have to actually be debugging something.

Comment: Please add a break point to start the debugging. Then it will be shown in `Debug -> Windows`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why my Visual Studio Community 2019 doesn't have the Modules option
>   under Debug > Windows and how to repair it?

**First**, I agree with **iteme86**, the **Modules** window will only show up **during debugging process**. You can [see this document about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-modules-window?view=vs-2019).

**As the official document said**,

> During Visual Studio debugging, the Modules window lists and shows
>   information about the DLLs and executables (.exe files) your app uses.

[image]

**So** you should start debugging your program, and then you can call **Modules** Window.